# How does the model binder figure out which user input to bind?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I use the **MVC** designer to create a `strongly typed view`, it will automatically write code to **model bind** UI input with model properties. But assume my view is not strongly typed with the model. Assume my model has 5 properties that can be bound, and the UI is sending 10 field inputs.

How does **MVC** cleverly figure out which field should be bound with which property?

Comment: Your form posts back name/values pairs based on the `name` and `value` attributes of the form controls. The `DefaultModelBinder` reads them and if it finds a match in the model, its sets the corresponding properties value.

Comment: @StephenMuecke if you'd need votes please post as a answers! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inputs should have a name attribute, and those names should match what's in your MVC post action's model properties. Say for example:

Your Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="Address" /> or @Html.TextBox("Address")
```

MVC Action:

```
public ActionResult SubmitPerson(Person p)
{
    //p.Address will have the value from the input with the name="Address"
}
```